# protecting files for download just for user that has credit in his/her acount?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wanna creat a website for downloading some files (pdf,word,xls, such as these files), each file has pice for example a.pdf is 10$ and b.pdf id 20$. For example usern "x" has 12$, how can i prevent this user for download file b.pdf ? Please giv me suggestions. You know i know that i can have membership system that can hqve roles for accessing folders but how about files ? Or you think i dont need to register users they can pay online price for each file, for example you select a.pdf and you will connect to paypal or others and you`ll pay, if you pay the link will be shown but how about if the user copy the link and send it to him/her friends ? Thank you

Comment: You might want to look into a premade shopping cart with digital download capabilties. I'm not fluent with their names/featuresets, but there are carts that can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I would use a generic handler, like SLaks suggests: Add New -> Generic Handler (.ashx) file.  Then in the handler class:

```
public class CustomImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Get file name from query string and check balance for that file extension... read the file into aStream

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/...";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", GetTheFileName()));
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(aStream.ToArray());
        }
}
```

Then the image hyperlinks are:

http://yourdomain.path/../CustomImageHandler.ashx?filename=file1.pdf

Comment: yes i`m tring to use this i think this is another way for beter protectong. Thank you

Comment: i used this way it worked for me grate. thanks for your kindness :x

Comment: Glad to help. Please keep in mind that this way of doing it affects performance. IIS is very efficient at serving files, like images, from URLs, but by doing this we are returning the files ourselves, which is not as efficient.

Answer (score 5):

You should put the files off of the web root (so that they cannot be accessed by URL).

Then, you can write an ASHX file or MVC action that takes a filename, checks whether the logged-in user is allowed to access it, and, if so, returns the file by calling `Response.TransmitFile`.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a page that accepts the file id as a GET parameter, and have the code behind check against their balance.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it when the transaction completed successfullu it will return true and i can check if the returned value is true the file cqn be download with the current user. Thanks for your help :x